# Mejor forma de mostrar datos en tabla de React

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una página web usando el stack MERN, pero en este momento estoy tratando de mostrar aproximadamente 100000 registros en una tabla  luego exportar esos datos a excel. Ya está funcionando correctamente todo el proceso, trae los datos desde el backend y se muestran en la tabla en la parte de frontend y también está generando el archivo excel.

El problema que tengo es que al momento de mostrar toda esa cantidad de datos, la página empieza a funcionar de manera muy lenta.Me gustaría saber que puedo hacer para evitar afectar el funcionamiento de mi página.

Comment: Es obvio que la pagina comenzaria a actuar muy lenta cuando le propones al backend traerte 100000 registros, eso es una locura!, normalmente lo usual son entre 20 a 50 registros por carga, y luego si deseas cargar mas informacion entonces se solicita mediante un paginador, un infinite scroll o algo que te permita crear una accion para recibir mas datos de 20 en 20, 50 en 50 o cuantos desees, pero lo ideal no es mostrar nunca toda tu base de datos entera.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es limitar desde el backend los datos que traes al frontend (Oye! pero yo quiero traer esos 100000 datos si o si), entonces no hay solucion simplemente, los recursos de una maquina son limitados, tu ordenador no es un servidor de la nasa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria bueno que realices una paginación para el backend de tal manera que no te ocupe mucho rato pedir tantos datos, también puedes mejorar el rendimiento de react implementando esta librería para crear una lista virtual es decir que no se creen 100000 contenedores, solo los que sean visibles.

Su funcionamiento es de la siguiente manera, muestra lo que necesites pero quita lo que el usuario no ve.

[image: Funcionamiento de virtual scroll]

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-virtual